# Exporting as .apk & project files location not known when using LuaEclipse (beginner)

Tags: android, eclipse, lua, apk, coronasdk

I am trying to create an .apk file. I see a new .apk saved on my desktop, but it is just a file with an extension with no data inside it.

I just recently moved from Corona SDK to LuaEclipse and what I need now is an explanation on how to combine all my files.

I have had a .lua file with other data such as images and sounds in a Project Files folder (when using Corona). Now I want to export these all files as .apk (to export by using Eclipse), but I can't because I don't know where to find the location of Project Files in LuaEclipse in order to put .lua file and other files in it.

I am a beginner so I apologize if the problem is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

LuaEclipse is not a tool for writing Lua applications. Or at least, not in the way you're trying to use it. It is an IDE, but since Lua is a scripting language, you need a runtime to make Lua scripts actually work.

Or to put it another way, LuaEclipse and Corona do completely different things. You can't replace Corona with LuaEclispe. Corona is a runtime for writing applications with Lua. LuaEclispe is just an Eclipse plugin that provides support for the Lua language. It doesn't provide an actual runtime.

Comment: tell me then what to do with my .lua file. It is created and it is working. Users also recommend Koneki. If there is an option that would allow me to export as .apk with a variety of preferences, if I got a .lua file with project files, then how can Eclipse help me. I can create a Lua project, but how is the final .apk file is exported with all the things that I need in it?

Comment: @Tema: Created and working *in what*? What environment are you running it in? And don't just say LuaEclipse, because that's an IDE, not a Lua runtime. How do you execute your script, such that you know it's working?