# Lua to be exported as .apk in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, lua, apk, coronasdk

What I need is to create my .apk file with Eclipse. My application is based on .lua file and other files like sounds and images.

P.S. I was using LuaEclipse but you can recommend me something else if it is also related with Eclipse.

I am trying to create an .apk file. I see a new .apk saved on my desktop, but it is just a file with an extension with no data inside it.

I just recently moved from Corona SDK to LuaEclipse and what I need now is an explanation on how to combine all my files.

I have had a .lua file with other data such as images and sounds in a Project Files folder (when using Corona). Now I want to export these all files as .apk (to export by using Eclipse), but I can't because I don't know where to find the location of Project Files in LuaEclipse in order to put .lua file and other files in it.

I am a beginner so I apologize if the problem is not clear. Let me know about my inaccuracies, please, thanks a lot

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exporting as .apk & project files location not known when using LuaEclipse (beginner)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808244/exporting-as-apk-project-files-location-not-known-when-using-luaeclipse-begi)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The correct solution to not getting an answer for your question is not to post it again.

Answer (score 0):

Better you get .apk file from corona sdk.

Answer (score 0):

For those who use Corona SDK to code their Native Android and iOS games, working without a proper IDE can be a nightmare at times. This is where CIDER comes in. CIDER hooks up directly to the Corona SDK and acts as it’s local IDE, and will speed up your development time dramatically.

CIDER is available for both Windows and Mac environments and has an array of very appealing features:

[Download](http://www.mydevelopersgames.com/CIDER/index.html)

and another-one IDE is

One of the very best IDEs for programming in Lua (and Corona SDK) for Windows.  It supports auto-completion, code hinting, syntax coloring, all sorts of awesome features.  I use other JetBrains software (PhpStorm) as well, so it felt very natural to me.  The layout and feature set is very similar to NetBeans or Eclipse.  Since the various features and setup is a bit more complex, take some time and read over the tutorial I wrote on Corona SDK development on Windows,

[Download](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html)